# How to set different texts in the TextViews populated with inflater?

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, layout-inflater

## template.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/header"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/template_linear_layout_container"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/template_linear_layout">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/template_title_TV"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="ALL"
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I created a TextView inside template.xml and I populated this linear layout of template.xml inside **parent_view** using inflater.

```
for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
    View container_template = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.templates, parent_layout, false);
    parent_layout.addView(container_template);
    TextView title_tv_template = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.template_title_TV);
    title_tv_template.setText(1+i+"text changed ");
}
```

I want to change text of each populated textview but above code changes text on of only first textview.

Comment: and `ID` is a number, since they always point to the same id, then its always the same resource (a TextView) that is being targeted. You either need an ID for each different `View`, or have them a single instance inside another unique `View`.. so a "mainLayout", with 3 "LinearLayout" (a,b,c), then using `mainLayout.a.title`, `mainLayout.b.title`, `mainLayout.c.title`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Bonatti](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4903925/bonatti) pointed out, `findViewById()` targets the same resource three times. So, instead of accessing `template_title_TV`  directly,I accessed it through `container_template` view:

```
TextView title_tv_template = (TextView)container_template.findViewById(R.id.template_title_TV);
```

Answer (score 0):

The above code is wrong, you should set the text first and add it to the parent view next..

```
for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
    View container_template = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.templates, parent_layout, false);
    TextView title_tv_template = (TextView) container_template. findViewById(R.id.template_title_TV);
    title_tv_template.setText(1+i+"text changed ");
    parent_layout.addView(container_template);
}
```

This code will work..